# my code at a particular line is throwing nullpointerexception

Tags: android

```
          db.execSQL("create table Student(id INTEGER primary key autoincrement , name TEXT,branch TEXT,college TEXT);");
```

this line is throwing Java.Lang.null pointer exception

Comment: Your db is null. Make sure you're using getWritableDatabase() before using the db.

Answer (score 3):

First correct this Change `Field Type` `auto-increment` to `AUTOINCREMENT`

```
    String TABLE_NAME="Student";

    String CREATE_DB_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + " name TEXT,branch TEXT,college TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
```

and make sure your `db` is not `NULL` at `db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);` position.

Comment: M D I don't think so that error in creating table returned NPE, I think db is null in OP code.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan ya yu're right. but i show another mistake to OP. and check my edited answer....